# Conversion failed when converting varchar value to int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am getting error while trying to execute the SP. pls help

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'INSERT INTO INVESTOR_ACCOUNT     VALUES('253361',' to data type int.
```

This is my SP

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[RM_INVESTOR_ACCOUNTS_INSERT]
@AccountNo varchar(20), @InvestorID integer, @SaleDate datetime
As
Begin
declare @query nvarchar(max) 
set @query ='INSERT INTO INVESTOR_ACCOUNT VALUES('''+ @AccountNo+ ''','+@InvestorID+','+@SaleDate+ ')'
print @query
End
```

Executed with below command

```
exec RM_INVESTOR_ACCOUNTS_INSERT '253361',1,'2003-12-24 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `+` is ambiguous.  It can mean either addition of numbers or string concatenation.  You have numbers mixed in, so it is interpreted as addition.

So, do explicit conversion.  Something like:

```
set @query ='INSERT INTO INVESTOR_ACCOUNT
    VALUES('''+ cast(@AccountNo as varchar(255)) + ''', '+cast(@InvestorID as varchar(255)) +','+@SaleDate+ ')';
```

EDIT:

For the date, this should work:

```
set @query ='INSERT INTO INVESTOR_ACCOUNT
    VALUES('''+ cast(@AccountNo as varchar(255)) + ''', '+cast(@InvestorID as varchar(255)) +', ''' + @SaleDate + ''')';
```

It will use a default formats.  The key is putting the values in single quotes in the string.

You can be explicit with the format by doing:

```
set @query ='INSERT INTO INVESTOR_ACCOUNT
    VALUES('''+ cast(@AccountNo as varchar(255)) + ''', '+cast(@InvestorID as varchar(255)) +', ''' + convert(varchar(10), @SaleDate, 121) + ''')';
```

This uses YYYY-MM-DD format, which SQL Server generally understands.

Comment: Doesn't date need casting/converting too?

Comment: need to cast Date as well. Can you tell me how to convert?

Comment: Thanks... But the second one(putting the date values in single quotes) is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
set @query ='INSERT INTO INVESTOR_ACCOUNT VALUES('''+ @AccountNo+ ''','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@InvestorID)+',CONVERT(DATETIME,'''+CONVERT(VARDHAR,@SaleDate,113)+ '',113')'
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.